# cannot load http://www.google.co.uk/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, load, cross-domain, access-control

I just simply want to load google, in a div using a anchor tags click function. But I am getting this error:

```
cannot load http://www.google.co.uk/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I am trying to access it this way:

```
$(".someclass").load("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

I know that cross domain is restricted, but is there any way to do this?
I tried jquery's ajax function too. but no success.
some suggestions pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a proxy script on your server. Call that proxy script from your front end so you are effectively calling back the original server.

$('.someclass').load('proxy.php?url=http://www.google.co.uk');

The server side proxy then fetches the requested url and returns it to the front-end.

Make sure to white list the urls so the script cannot be exploited. Instead of passing a real url between the front end and the proxy script, use logical keys.

$('.someclass').load('proxy.php?**page=google_uk**');

In your proxy script, you call http://www,google.co.uk when google_uk is requested. If someone tries to exploit your script by passing a url or an invalid key, you can return a 403 http error code (not authorized).

If you need only a certain part of the page, it's good to know that the load method also accepts a css selector like this:

$('.someclass').load('proxy.php?page=google_uk **div#search_form**');

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok. But what should be there in proxy.php. I mean how should I code it. Is there any kind of special coding involved in it?!

Comment: There's nothing special to it. It sends an http request to the requested url (or logical key) and returns the result to the front-end. I did not provide code as I did not which server environment you were working with. You can use cUrl in PHP, as documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

Answer (score 2):

You can not load Google because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

To make a XHR call, the protocol, domain and port must match.

If you are on `http://bla.example.com`, you can change your domain like so...

```
document.domain = 'example.com';
```

To get around it, you can proxy the data server side or use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: I didnt get your point. U mean to say that..the reqest to access google is from the same source, and thats y it is not loading!?

Comment: @mad What point? I was simply stating the sandbox that browsers follow, and specifically the limitation you are hitting. Then I suggested two possible workarounds.